# javascript and mysql getting data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to replace static data to data from sql database. The code below is in javascript, and i am only familiar getting data with php from mysql. So how could i do this in my javascript? Any examples?

```
exampleTeams  = _.shuffle(["New Jersey Devils","New York Islanders","New York Rangers","Philadelphia Flyers","Pittsburgh Penguins","Boston Bruins","Buffalo Sabres","Montreal Canadiens","Ottawa Senators","Toronto Maple Leafs","Carolina Hurricanes","Florida Panthers","Tampa Bay Lightning","Washington Capitals","Winnipeg Jets","Chicago Blackhawks","Columbus Blue Jackets","Detroit Red Wings","Nashville Predators","St. Louis Blues","Calgary Flames","Colorado Avalanche","Edmonton Oilers","Minnesota Wild","Vancouver Canucks","Anaheim Ducks"}
```

Comment: How are you running your JavaScript? NodeJS? Windows Script Host? Classic ASP JScript?

Comment: You need a PHP script that will extract the data from the database, echo them in JSON format and you also need AJAX to fetch the data dynamically

Comment: i use xampp. Do you have any examples?

Comment: xampp supports PHP and Perl for server side programming, not JavaScript. Are you asking how to connect directly to the database from a browser?!

Comment: that's not secure @Quentin i want to do it with php and display data in this javascript variable.

Comment: @swipeales — Well, yes … but it is what you asked in the question!